# Multipart request fails with 415 while WebFluxTest passes

Tags: spring-boot, multipartform-data

I've created a RESTful API endpoint for uploading images. I try to test this endpoint with `TestWebClient`. Somehow my tests are getting green, but while calling the endpoint with e.g. Postman, the app is responding with a 415.

My assumption is, that there is some problem with `@RequestPart` and `FilePart` (maybe some wrong deserialization?), but there is not a lot of documentation about how to actually set it up correctly.

**Additional Information:** By switching from `FilePart` to `MultiPartFile` as the parameter for the POST method, the Integration Test starts failing with a 415 and the request with Postman is responding a 201.

**Question:**
How do I have to set up my Controller and/or Integration Test, so that my tests are passing and I can call the API with Postman without an error?

```java
// Image Upload Controller

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/images")
class UploadImageController {

    @PostMapping
    ResponseEntity<Object> uploadImage(@RequestPart(name = "image") FilePart image) {
        // TODO call service here.
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).build();
    }
}
```

And here is the Integration Test

```java
@WebFluxTest
class CreateImageTest {

    private final static String IMAGE_URI = "/api/v1/images";

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient testClient;

    @DisplayName("GIVEN I am an authenticated user WHEN I create a new image THEN the API indicates a success.")
    @Test
    void happyPathTest() {
        MultipartBodyBuilder multipartBodyBuilder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
        multipartBodyBuilder.part("image", new ClassPathResource("test-image.png")).headers(h -> {
            h.setContentDispositionFormData("image", "test-image.png");
            h.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
        });


        testClient.post().uri(IMAGE_URI)
                .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
                .bodyValue(multipartBodyBuilder.build());
                .exchange().expectStatus().isCreated(); // this assumtion is true
    }
}
```

**HTTP request from Postman**

```http
POST /api/v1/images HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Content-Length: 182
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="test-image.png"
Content-Type: image/png

(data)
----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
```

This requests prints the following log (I've enabled the log to print the HTTP request. This makes some problems with printing the image, therefore I've replaced this part with `[...]`:

```
2023-05-30T16:46:06.222+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header

java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1290) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:805) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:272) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2023-05-30T16:46:06.222+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@13d8b820:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@47077251:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8000 remote=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:51159]], Read direct from socket: [8192]
2023-05-30T16:46:06.223+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error state [CLOSE_CONNECTION_NOW] reported while processing request

java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1290) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1177) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:805) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:272) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:859) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1734) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.5.jar:10.1.5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2023-05-30T16:46:06.223+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [POST /api/v1/images HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.2
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: 9dea3323-33c8-4aff-82ad-a4383fa494b6
Host: localhost:8000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------850093464125968220605837
Content-Length: 21865

----------------------------850093464125968220605837
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="test-image.png"
Content-Type: image/png

PNG
[...]
2023-05-30T16:46:06.223+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@f07d066:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@45e8c1cd:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8000 remote=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:51158]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [CLOSED]
2023-05-30T16:46:06.223+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] o.apache.tomcat.util.threads.LimitLatch  : Counting down[http-nio-8000-exec-1] latch=2
2023-05-30T16:46:06.224+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Calling [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint@2a9c1537].closeSocket([org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@f07d066:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@45e8c1cd:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8000 remote=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:51158]])
2023-05-30T16:46:06.239+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters   : Set query string encoding to UTF-8
2023-05-30T16:46:06.241+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Security checking request POST /api/v1/images
2023-05-30T16:46:06.241+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase      :   No applicable constraints defined
2023-05-30T16:46:06.246+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.a.c.a.jaspic.AuthConfigFactoryImpl     : Loading persistent provider registrations from [/private/var/folders/8m/d3821lq90fxc363fyvm832p00000gn/T/tomcat.8000.10544593538486669327/conf/jaspic-providers.xml]
2023-05-30T16:46:06.246+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.a.c.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase    : Not subject to any constraint
2023-05-30T16:46:06.248+02:00  INFO 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/image]        : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-05-30T16:46:06.249+02:00  INFO 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-05-30T16:46:06.249+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2023-05-30T16:46:06.249+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
2023-05-30T16:46:06.249+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected FixedThemeResolver
2023-05-30T16:46:06.250+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@21738cc2
2023-05-30T16:46:06.251+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@1b258760
2023-05-30T16:46:06.251+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2023-05-30T16:46:06.251+02:00  INFO 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 2 ms
2023-05-30T16:46:06.275+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/api/v1/images", parameters={multipart}
2023-05-30T16:46:06.301+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Before fill(): parsingHeader: [false], parsingRequestLine: [false], parsingRequestLinePhase: [0], parsingRequestLineStart: [0], byteBuffer.position(): [8192], byteBuffer.limit(): [8192], end: [342]
2023-05-30T16:46:06.302+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@13d8b820:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@47077251:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8000 remote=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:51159]], Read from buffer: [0]
2023-05-30T16:46:06.302+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@13d8b820:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@47077251:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:8000 remote=/[0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1]:51159]], Read direct from socket: [8192]
2023-05-30T16:46:06.302+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer      : Received [[...]----------------------------850093464125968220605837--
]
2023-05-30T16:46:06.310+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.sap.image.api.adapter.in.UploadimageController#uploadImage(FilePart)
2023-05-30T16:46:06.332+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.web.method.HandlerMethod             : Could not resolve parameter [0] in org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> com.sap.image.api.adapter.in.UploadimageController.uploadimage(org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.FilePart): Content-Type 'image/png' is not supported
2023-05-30T16:46:06.336+02:00  WARN 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'image/png' is not supported]
2023-05-30T16:46:06.337+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE
2023-05-30T16:46:06.341+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
2023-05-30T16:46:06.345+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/image/error", parameters={multipart}
2023-05-30T16:46:06.346+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2023-05-30T16:46:06.361+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2023-05-30T16:46:06.362+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Tue May 30 16:46:06 CEST 2023, status=415, error=Unsupported Media Type, path=/api (truncated)...]
2023-05-30T16:46:06.399+02:00 DEBUG 26560 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 415
```